# Which event is raised when the mouse wheel is scrolled directly over a ScrollViewer's scroll bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a WPF window that contains this ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{StaticResource AccentColor2}" UseLayoutRounding="True" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
    <StackPanel Margin="50,0,50,50"...>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The code-behind is attached to the PreviewMouseWheel event, so I can react to the mouse wheel being scrolled.

This works fine, except when the cursor is directly over the ScrollViewer's scroll bar. The control scrolls, but the event is never fired and my code won't execute. Why is this happening and how can I react to this specific case?

Comment: Do you mean - when you scroll with mouse wheel the event is fired, but when you scroll with mouse down on the scroll bar it doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the event fires when I scroll over the child elements, but not over the scroll bar. If you mean by 'with mouse down' that the left mouse button is pressed: No. I don't press any of the mouse buttons. Simply moving the cursor from the child controls to the scroll bar is enough to prevent the event from firing.

Comment: Well, i just created a mock project to try this, and it works perfect for me.. 
The only thing i can think about that there is some control that is "Transparent" and is margined over the scroll bar or something bizzar like this. It works for me.

Comment: Okay, I'm really stupid. I think I lost the focus when working with my code. My ScrollViewer was placed inside a custom UserControl, which I've embedded in my MainWindow... as the content of another ScrollViewer. So the scroll bar I've seen all the time was the scroll bar of my MainWindow's ScrollViewer. I'm going to have a break, bang my head against the wall for about half an hour and consider deleting this question.

Comment: HA! So i was right with the other control thing.. there you go ^_^ good luck